# How to proven a programming function in math

Tags: algorithm, math

**Here is a programming problem:**

Four integers A, B, C and D are given. A mix of them is any zero-indexed array M consisting of these four integers in some order. If all the given integers are unique, then there are 24 different mixes of them.

The best mix of the given integers is any mix M of them such that the value of:
  F(M) = abs(M[0]-M[1]) + abs(M[1]-M[2]) + abs(M[2]-M[3]) is maximal.

Write a function:

class Solution { int solution(int A, int B, int C, int D); }

that, given four integers A, B, C and D, finds their best mix M and returns the value of F(M).

For example, consider the following integers:
  A = 5    B = 3    C = -1    D = 5

The best mix of them is as follows:

M[0] =  5

M[1] = -1

M[2] =  5

M[3] =  3

and the result is F(M) = 14.

Assume that:

A, B, C and D are integers within the range [−1,000,000..1,000,000].

Complexity:

expected worst-case time complexity is O(1);
expected worst-case space complexity is O(1).

**My idea is:**

1. Create an array N amd sort the number in descendant sequence
2. Assign M0[0] = N[3], M[1] = N[0], M[2] = N[2], M[3] = V[1]
3. Thur, Abs[Largest Number - Smallest Number] + [Smallest Number - 2nd Largest Number] + [2nd Largest Number - 2nd Smallest Number]

**How can I prove my idea is correct? how to prove it in math way?**

Comment: I think you are barking up the wrong tree as your assignment is asking you to write _code_ to do this.  You can just iterate over the 24 configurations and return the best one.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen True, although the general problem (with _N_ integers) is still interesting.

Comment: Btw your solution is not correct. Consider this example: `[1, 50, 51, 100]`. Your ordering would be `[100, 1, 51, 50]`, which would total to `149`, but `[50, 100, 1, 51]` is a better ordering with a score of `199`. Maybe better split _N_ in two halves and take one element at a time from each half, from big to small? (not sure if this is optimal either).

Answer (score 1):

As it seems that you are not asked a general solution and the problem size is tiny, the most straightforward way is to hard-code the 24 permutations in calls to a function that evaluates the cost and keeps the best:

```
F(A, B, C, D); 
F(A, B, D, C); 
F(A, C, B, D);
...
```

As a minor optimization, you can drop half of the cases, which are symmetrical (the function evaluates the same way left-to-right or right-to-left), so that only 12 calls are needed.

---

**Advanced note:**

I found this quote from Wikipedia: "In weighted complete graphs with non-negative edge weights, the weighted longest path problem is the same as the Travelling salesman path problem, because the longest path always includes all vertices."

If I am right, we are precisely in this case so that the problem is NP-hard. This would mean that there is no hope of finding a method much better than exhaustive search, as done above. (Anyway, this instance of the problem enjoys the triangular inequality, which might make it easier...)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem, So I have come up with an approach that could be employed for general N as well.

Let me first explain my approach for the 4 integers and then I will explain how we can extend our approach for more than 4 integers.

So I am taking into account the given example

```
Array arr = [A=5, B=-1, C=5, D=3].
```

Steps to follow:-

```
1. Sort all the numbers, now you the list as follows - -1,3,5,5.
2. Keep two pointers one start=0 and other end=3.
3. Take a new list say new_arr and Append arr[3] to new_arr i.e 5. Now without much thinking append arr[0] and arr[1] to both sides of 5.
4. So our new_arr looks like = -1,5,3.
5. Increment start += 2 and Decrement end -= 1.
6. Now we take arr[end] i.e arr[2] = 5 and we check whether abs(new_arr[0]-arr[2]) > abs(new_arr[length]-arr[2]) or not, if yes then append arr[2] to start else append it to the end.
7. Now our final list looks like - 5,-1,5,3.
8. Now if you calculate the abs(new_arr[i]-new_arr[i+1]) you will get 14.
```

You can test the above approach for the input `100,1,50,51` as well and it will you `199`.

Now let's talk about extending this to general `N`.

So for that once we are done with step 4. So from then on for each `start+1` and `end+1` alternatively till `start < end`, we check the condition as whether

```
abs(new_arr[start]-arr[cur_index]) > abs(new_arr[end]-arr[cur_index]) or not.
```

And based on this check on each iteration we append to either front or back.

Like a Greedy approach basically and it should work because we are kind of creating a mountain with Largest element in the middle and other small slopes on either sides.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you don't prove that it works, I will not rely on this heuristic approach.

Comment: @YvesDaoust do you want me to write a program and test it on a bunch of cases, will that do ?

Comment: No, a few tests will never convince me because you are unsure that the coverage is sufficient. I need a mathematical argument.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating all possible combinations is unnecessary - a simple sort coupled with extracting the values from the resulting collection in proper order is all that's needed. You want to have the smallest input value "between" the largest and second-largest value, and the second-smallest value next to the largest value, all done in order to maximize the differences of the various elements. Take the following function (in Clojure, a Lisp variant):

```
(defn maximal-func [n]
  (let [m  (sort > n)
        m0 (second m)         ; second-largest value
        m1 (last m)           ; smallest input value
        m2 (first m)          ; largest input value
        m3 (second(rest m))]  ; second-smallest value
  (reduce + (map #(Math/abs %) [(- m0 m1) (- m1 m2) (- m2 m3)]))))
```

Here we take the input collection `n` and sort it in descending order to produce 'm', then extract the values as required to obtain the desired result. Then perform the calculations (m0 - m1), (m1 - m2), (m2 - m3), take the absolute value of each of these sub-results, and sum them.

I'd be interested to see a data set for which this function doesn't produce the desired result.